# Emulator from Java ME Platform SDK does not display text on Windows 7

Tags: java, sdk, java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit

I am trying to use vanilla j2me emulator from Java ME Platform SDK 3.2 on Windows 7 but it doesn't show any text on its screen.

It draws all ui controls but there is no text both in my midlet and in in emulator menu.

I assume that this is some kind of font problem I am not really sure. Does someone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Hi @Eugeny Loy did you find the solution? If yes please let me know.

Comment: @Sunny nope. Struggled with it for some time and haven't found a way to fix it. Have no clue what caused this issue. Funny thing that it magically cured by itself when I checked it again after ~year.

Comment: @Sunny BTW if you'll find the solution, please post it here, so anyone with this obscure issue could find the info on how to fix it.